# Iterate Android phone files

Tags: delphi

I am writing a Delphi VCL application and I need to iterate the files on my phone and SD card using `FindFirst` and `FindNext` etc.

The phone is attached using USB and I can see the device and file system using Windows Explorer.

I expected to simply put in the path to the SD Card and use `FindFirst`, `FindNext`, e.g.:

```
procedure MyProc;
var
  sr: TSearchRec;
begin
  if FindFirst('This PC\My Phone Name\SD card\DCIM\Camera\*.jpg', faAnyFile, sr) = 0 then
    repeat
      Showmessage(sr.name);
      //blah
      ...
    until FindNext(sr) <> 0;
  FindClose(sr);
end;
```

Nothing has worked so far with Path not found errors
I'm using Delphi 11.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you can't iterate through Android phone files as you would do with local files is the fact that when you connect your phone to the computer you don't really get direct access to phones file structure.

Instead all the files are being transferred from the phone to your computer using [Media Transfer Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol)

Now the reason why you can see the files from your phone in windows explorer as if they would be stored on computer is because windows explorer has a built-in functionality to work with MTP protocol. But even then if you look closely you will notice that when viewing files directly from your phone some of the usual explorer options are missing, context menu is different and so on.

Comment: Thank you Freddie, I'll take a look at this

Comment: Surely you mean SilverWarior?